# Python - Pandas - Dataframe How to add notnull to a column when using .count

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a new column that will count all ids but exclude a few rows of customers where the customer's ID has a certain prefix and has no repeat orders

```
df['newcolumn'] = df[(df.notnull['Date']) & (df['ID'].str.contains('prefix')) & (df['Repeat order'] == 'No')].groupby(['ID'], as_index=False).count()
```

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Still no difference when I replaced [] with () to resolve above error

Answer (score 1):

change

```
df.notnull['Date']
```

to

```
df['Date'].notnull()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I already tried that option too and I got TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'method' and 'bool'